# Approximate a known function by a sum of real power function

Tags: approximation, regression

Given a known function $f(x):[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$.
(For example, $f(x) = e^{-\ln^2 \left(3x-\frac{3}{2} \right)} \mathbb{I}_{\{\frac{1}{2}<x<2\}} $ over the support $[a,b] = \left[\frac{1}{2} ; 2 \right] $)

[image]

I want to approximate the function $f(x)$, over its support $[a,b]$,  by a sum of piecewise power function as follows
$$f(x) \approx  \sum_{n=1}^N c_i x^{ r_i}\mathbb{I}_{\{a_i<x<b_i\}}$$
where $r_i, c_i,a_i,b_i \in \Bbb R$ and $a\leq a_i <b_i \leq b$ for $i=1,...,N$

The problem can be seen as:

> Find the smallest $N$ such that there exists
> $(r_i,c_i,a_i,b_i)_{i=1,..,N}$ satisfying
> $$\underset{x\in[a,b]}{\text{max}} \left|f(x) - \sum_{n=1}^N c_i x^{r_i} \mathbb{I}_{\{a_i<x<b_i\}}  \right| < \epsilon \tag{1} $$
> with $\epsilon \in \Bbb R$ is given

Do you have any idea or reference for this problem?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just a quick remark, isn't it there a mistake in the picture? Since calculating the function in a point $x=1$ would give $e^{-(ln(0))^2}$ which is undefined.

Comment: @A.Gonus Thank you. It's a typo. I just corrected the function.

Comment: One more question: can the restrictions always be fulfilled? In other words, if you are given $N=1$ and $\epsilon$ very close to zero you need to find $r_1,a_1,b_1,c_1$ that the difference between the function and approximation is close to zero. But that is not always possible... Like if your function is $cos(x)$ and you consider the support $[0,1000]$, then any power function can't be close to it. Or do I miss something?

Comment: @A.Gonus Yes, your comment is very pertinent! In fact, I would like to approximate the function $f(x)$ by a smallest $N$ power functions $c_i x^{r_i} \mathbb{I}_{\{a_i<x<b_i\}}$. So, indeed, the real question is find the smallest value $N$ such that there exists $(r_i,c_i,a_i,b_i)_{i=1,..,N}$ satisfying $(1)$. I just modified the question.

Comment: The way this is written, it could be satisfied with a Taylor polynomial for $f$ over the entire interval (I.e., all your power functions have the same domain). Do you want the power functions to have disjoint domains?